# What is the algorithm for the "Shorten" command in Maple?

Tags: maple

There is a package in Maple called "PolynomialTools". That has a command "Shorten".  Does anybody know on what algorithm this is based.  The maple manual does not explain much.

Example:

with(PolynomialTools):
Shorten(x^2+x+1,x);

Comment: i love the question but mapleprimes.com is a better place to ask it. The people who created this package often answer questions there.

Answer (score 1):

That [PolynomialTools:-Shorten](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=PolynomialTools/Shorten) Maple Library command is a renamed version of the [shorten](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~hoeij/lib/NEW/shorten) command written by [Mark van Hoeij](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~hoeij/).

That `PolynomialTools:-Shorten` command is based on the  (now deprecated) Maple Library command [polytools[shorten]](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=polytools%28deprecated%29/shorten).

See [here](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~hoeij/maple.html), for van Hoeij's Maple page. I did not see a reference to it on his [publications](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~hoeij/papers.html) page. It may be that `shorten` was first implemented before 2001.

Perhaps you could ask him.

Comment: Thank you! I found Mark's code and am going through it. It doesn't seem as the algorithm gives always the best answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the "shorten" command does to a polynomial $f(x)

$\bullet$ make a substitution to remove the $x^(n-1)$ term

$\bullet$  scale $x$ by some rational number,

$\bullet$  if $\mbox{deg } (f,x)=2$ then square-free factor the discriminant

I was hoping that through some substitutions in $x$ it would find a polynomial with a minimum height, but it doesn't do that.